# How to select from table where the table name is a local variable(informix)

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix, dynamic-sql

I want to select from table where the **table name is a local variable** and **the column name is another local variable** but i get the following error :

The specified table `ll_tb_name`is not in the database

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rmg_request_file ( al_task_code integer)
RETURNING integer as byte;


DEFINE ll_task_code integer;
DEFINE ll_pdf_column varchar(50);
DEFINE ll_tb_name varchar(60);
DEFINE ll_request_file REFERENCES BYTE;


SELECT pdf_column,table_name INTO  ll_pdf_column ,ll_tb_name  FROM rnmtask WHERE task_code = al_task_code;


FOREACH   

SELECT  ll_pdf_column into  ll_request_file FROM ll_tb_name   

return ll_request_file  with resume ;
end foreach;

end procedure
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a recent enough version of Informix (11.70), you should be able to use Dynamic SQL in SPL like this:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TABLE rnmtask
(
    pdf_column VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    table_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    task_code  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO rnmtask VALUES("symbol", "elements", 1);
INSERT INTO rnmtask VALUES("name", "elements", 2);
INSERT INTO rnmtask VALUES("atomic_number", "elements", 3);

CREATE PROCEDURE rmg_request_file(al_task_code INTEGER)
    RETURNING VARCHAR(255) AS colval;

    DEFINE ll_pdf_column    VARCHAR(50);
    DEFINE ll_tb_name       VARCHAR(60);
    DEFINE stmt             VARCHAR(255);
    DEFINE result           VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT pdf_column, table_name
      INTO ll_pdf_column, ll_tb_name
      FROM rnmtask
     WHERE task_code = al_task_code;

    LET stmt = "SELECT " || ll_pdf_column || " FROM " || ll_tb_name;
    PREPARE p FROM stmt;
    DECLARE C CURSOR FOR p;
    OPEN C;
    WHILE sqlcode = 0
        FETCH C INTO result;
        IF sqlcode != 0 THEN
            EXIT WHILE;
        END IF;
        RETURN result WITH RESUME;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE C;
    FREE C;
    FREE p;

END PROCEDURE;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE rmg_request_file(1);
EXECUTE PROCEDURE rmg_request_file(2);
EXECUTE PROCEDURE rmg_request_file(3);

ROLLBACK;
```

This assumes you have a convenient Table of Elements in your database:

```
CREATE TABLE elements
(
    atomic_number   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT c1_elements
                    CHECK (atomic_number > 0 AND atomic_number < 120),
    symbol          CHAR(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT c2_elements,
    name            CHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT c3_elements,
    atomic_weight   DECIMAL(8, 4) NOT NULL,
    period          SMALLINT NOT NULL
                    CHECK (period BETWEEN 1 AND 7),
    group           CHAR(2) NOT NULL
                    -- 'L' for Lanthanoids, 'A' for Actinoids
                    CHECK (group IN ('1', '2', 'L', 'A', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                                     '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13',
                                     '14', '15', '16', '17', '18')),
    stable          CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL
                    CHECK (stable IN ('Y', 'N'))
);

INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  1, 'H',   'Hydrogen',        1.0079, 1, '1',  'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  2, 'He',  'Helium',          4.0026, 1, '18', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  3, 'Li',  'Lithium',         6.9410, 2, '1',  'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  4, 'Be',  'Beryllium',       9.0122, 2, '2',  'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  5, 'B',   'Boron',          10.8110, 2, '13', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  6, 'C',   'Carbon',         12.0110, 2, '14', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  7, 'N',   'Nitrogen',       14.0070, 2, '15', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  8, 'O',   'Oxygen',         15.9990, 2, '16', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES(  9, 'F',   'Fluorine',       18.9980, 2, '17', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 10, 'Ne',  'Neon',           20.1800, 2, '18', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 11, 'Na',  'Sodium',         22.9900, 3, '1',  'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 12, 'Mg',  'Magnesium',      24.3050, 3, '2',  'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 13, 'Al',  'Aluminium',      26.9820, 3, '13', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 14, 'Si',  'Silicon',        28.0860, 3, '14', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 15, 'P',   'Phosphorus',     30.9740, 3, '15', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 16, 'S',   'Sulphur',        32.0650, 3, '16', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 17, 'Cl',  'Chlorine',       35.4530, 3, '17', 'Y');
INSERT INTO elements VALUES( 18, 'Ar',  'Argon',          39.9480, 3, '18', 'Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prefix every occurrence of `ll_tb_name` and `ll_pdf_column` with the @ symbol, even in your `SELECT INTO`

Answer (score 0):

Use **NDS** (native dynamic SQL):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "SELECT  ll_pdf_column into  ll_request_file FROM :@ll_tb_name"
USING @ll_tb_name;
```

Comment: try to remove @ from SELECT statement: so make it "SELECT  ll_pdf_column into  ll_request_file FROM :ll_tb_name"

Comment: Could u write the whole procedure with your recommendation to solve this problem please

Comment: I am not familiar with informix, I suggested you NDS because it is in SQL standart and addressed your question, I understood It as how to query data from table which name is unknown at the compile time